# Retornar o valor máximo das somas da collection com MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Tenho uma `collection` no `MongoDB` e nela tem vários registros e preciso fazer a soma de uma coluna por **UF** e depois retornar o maior valor dessa soma. Por exemplo

```
UF: 'SP',
Valor: 10
----
UF: 'SP',
Valor: 23.5
----
UF: 'RJ',
Valor: 40
----
UF: 'PR',
Valor: 5
```

O que preciso fazer é somar os valores pelo estado, ou seja:

```
SP = 33.5
RJ = 40
PR = 5
```

E retornar o maior valor que no caso:

```
40 (que é de RJ)
```

Tudo isso com o mongoDB. Estou usando PHP, mas isso não interfere. O problema está na `query` que não sei fazer corretamente. Tentei fazer uma parecida com essa mas não funcionou, apenas retornou o número máximo de cada estado:

```
{
   {
    '$group' : {
        '_id' : '$UF',
        'Maximo' : { 
            $max: {
                {'$sum' : '$Valor'}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

O que preciso é retorne o número máximo da soma, não de todas, só o valor maior entre todas as somas. Isso gostaria de fazer sem precisar ficar dando `foreach` no PHP, por isso queria fazer tudo na query já.

Answer (score 1):

> Para pegar o valor máximo, independentemente do grupo:

```
db.Values.aggregate(
[        
    {
        $group : {
           _id :  null ,
           maximo: { $max: "$Valor" }
        }
    }
]    
)
```

> Para pegar os valores por grupo (UF):

```
db.Values.aggregate(
[        
    {
        $group : {
           _id :  "$UF" ,
           total: { $sum: "$Valor" },           
           count: { $sum: 1 }           
        }
    }
]    
)
```

> Para pegar somente o maior valor de um determinado grupo:

```
db.Values.aggregate(
[        
    {
        $group : {
           _id :  "$UF" ,
           total: { $sum: "$Valor" },           
           count: { $sum: 1 }                     
        }
    },    
    { 
        $sort : { total : -1} 
    },
    { 
        $limit : 1        
    },
]    
)
```

**Referencias:**

- [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/aggregation/)
- [MongoDB – Aggregate and Group example](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-aggregate-and-group-example/)
- [mongodb aggregation php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290809/mongodb-aggregation-php)
- [MongoDB driver](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php)

Comment: Nesse seu segundo exemplo ele irá retornar o valor da soma por estado. O que eu queria é que depois que ele fisesse isso, então ele retornaria só o maior valor e não todos.

Comment: @AlissonAcioli você quer além disso um limite e uma ordernação? seria isso no segundo exemplo?

Comment: @AlissonAcioli tem 3 respostas a última acredito que sirva pra seu proposito, dê uma verificada?

Comment: No segundo exemplo você faz 50% do que eu quero que é somar os valor da coluna "Valor" de acordo com cada estado. Vamos supor que ele retorne 5 estados, cada um com o "count" (soma do estado) diferente. Eu quero saber qual desses 5 estados tem a soma maior e trazer somente ele.

Comment: Pelo que vi, sua última resposta pode dar certo pra mim. Jaja irei testar e retorno aqui

Comment: @AlissonAcioli algum solução deu certo pra você?